# What does "global potential" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I ran into this:

> This year´s World Tourism Day highlights the global potential of tourism for socio-economic development.  With more than one billion international tourists now traveling the world each year, tourism has become a powerful and transformative force that is making a genuine difference in the lives of millions of people.<[Source](http://wtd.unwto.org/content/official-messages-world-tourism-day)>

I know what "potential" mean and what "global" mean but about their combination, I feel not sure.

Comment: What do you think *global* means, and what do you think *potential* means? Why can't you put those together?

Comment: @tchrist *global* means " ​relating to the ​whole ​world" and *potential* means "someone's or something's ​ability to ​develop, ​achieve, or ​succeed"

Comment: Not sure what the problem with a world-wide ability to get ahead would be.

Comment: @tchrist exactly what does a *world-wide ability* mean? *ability to make change all around the world*?

Comment: It can happen anywhere. I still don't understand your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In this context the world global refers to *all the people in the whole world* more than physical world itself.

And the world potential has some similar  meanings you can use in different contexts.The meaning for this word you thought is likely to be used in a context related to physics or generally science.

In this context the word potential was used as a synonym of the word *possible*.And  the definition  for this sense from Oxford Dictionary is that

> (often potential for/to do something) The possibility of something
>   happening or of someone doing something in the future.

And some related example sentences are

> They were of course unaware of the latent potential for economic
>   growth just around the corner.
>
> It has experienced strong growth in the past three years and has good
>   potential for future growth.
>
> the crane operator’s clear view reduces the potential for accidents.

So the organizers in this forum forecasts and takes attention how possible tourist movements   for the future can affect socially and economically a country or a city which has a potential to be visited by millions of people.

*http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/potential*
*Definition 1.1*